# SSRS Subscriptions - Change credentials to run under new user

Tags: security, reporting-services, subscriptions

I came across a fun problem today.  Basically, we have thousands of subscriptions setup under a few users to dump a report into a directory on a monthly basis.  One of these users was moved to a different role/department, and her credentials no longer have access to the folder where they were being dumped.  So, I think the easiest solution would be to switch all of her subscriptions over to one of the other users who still has access to the folders.

I already know how to update the Owner.  What I need to know is how to change the credential username.  It is one of the pieces of the ExtensionSettings in the Subscription table, but it appears to be encrypted.  I already have a script that will update the credential password based on the credential username, so I would think there would be a way to update the credential username based on the owner.

Comment: IMHO you should have people be nested in Organizational units, OUs, in active directory.  Not have individual patterns.  Then when a user changes departments it is up to whoever manages active directory to change it.  If you do not have AD set up and have thousands of subscriptions I would say you should set it up.  I would stay away from scripting the 'ReportServer' database.  If you break that thing in any way it could make the whole instance go down potentially and you would have to reinstall SSRS.

Comment: I'm with you on that.  And honestly, I am not sure how the AD is setup here.  Unfortunately, I'm the ETL Architect here, tasked with handling this issue (because why not?).  As much as I like new challenges, I think the potential fallout is a little too risky for my comfort.

Comment: See code below and handle with care.  I commented out the 'Select' statement to verify once ran.  I strongly suggest doing a few at a time and testing or better yet use on a replicated or test environment first.  MS is pretty squeamish on supporting the ReportServer database and direct altering is playing with fire.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this taken care of by writing a powershell script that works with the actual ExtensionSettings objects.  It's ugly, so I'm not going to post it in fear that someone would inadvertently crash their BI in using it.